# Prove $\int_0^{t_1}\int_0^{\tau}f(s)\ ds\ d\tau=\int_0^{t_1}(t_1-s)f(s)ds$

Tags: calculus, integration

**Problem**

Show:
$\int_0^{t_1}\int_0^{\tau}f(s)\ ds\  d\tau=\int_0^{t_1}(t_1-s)f(s)ds$.

**Attempt**

I did this by integrating by parts. The integral on the right is equivalent to \begin{align*}
\int_0^{t_1}t_1f(s)ds-\int_0^{t_1}sf(s)ds&=\int_0^{t_1}t_1f(s)ds-\left(s\int_0^{t_1}f(s) \ ds-\int_0^{t_1}\int_0^{\tau}f(s) \ ds \ d\tau \right)\\
&= \int_0^{t_1}\int_0^{\tau}f(s)\ ds\  d\tau
\end{align*}

**Question**

Was there a really easy way (without doing integration by parts) to see this result?

Comment: the original thing you are trying to prove is incorrect. As written the l.h.s. is just $t_2 \int_0^{t_1} f(s) ds $

Comment: Yes, thank-you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to use Fubini Theorem to change the order of integration.

Note that bound for $\tau$ changes to [$s,t_1$] after integration order exchanges because $s$ is from $0$ to $\tau$.

$$
\int_0^{t_1}\int_0^{\tau}f(s)\ ds\ d\tau=\int_0^{t_1}\int_{s}^{t_1}d\tau f(s)\:ds=\int_0^{t_1} (t_1-s)f(s)\:ds
$$

Comment: Ah we have to actually consider the triangular region and change limits accordingly...this is very embarrassing. Thank-you for your response!

Comment: Yes, when exchanges order of integration, we have to switch from lower triangular region to upper triangular region.